# A bit niche - noun? adjective?

Tags: meaning

I came across this sentence while I was reading an article and it got me very confused as to the definition of the word "*niche*"

> The bitter, terrible reality of the media world was clear to me even then. My pudgy face didn't fit. I didn't have enough glamour for Anna. In retrospect, perhaps my suggestion that The Blues Brothers should be shown every day at midnight was **a bit niche**. But that didn't matter.

I don't think I understand understand the definition of "*niche*" here. Is it a noun or an adjective? What does it mean in this sentence?i don't seem to be able to understand it... Does it mean it was not the correct time slot on TV? or that it was not the right tip?

Comment: Forgetting the part of speech label, 'a bit X' where X is a modifier, means that it is 'a little X' or 'somewhat X'. This leads one to think that X should be an adjective. It is somewhat informal and new to put a noun there meaning 'having somewhat the characteristics of an X'. It's one of those things: if a native speaker says it and means it then it's OK; if a non-native speaker says it (with an accent) it would sound wrong and ungrammatical. Know what I'm sayin?

Comment: @Mitch: New? I would argue that this is actually creating a new adjective from the noun; but either way, the process is as old as verbing (which is to say probably as old as language).

Comment: "Niche" is often used as an adjective today (e.g., "a niche book"), but not in the sense used here, so I'm inclined to Mitch's answer.

Comment: @gmcgath: Isn't it used in exactly the same sense as "a niche book"? My interpretation of the passage is that it says that a showing of *The Blues Brothers* every day at midnight would appeal to a very small number of people ...just like "a niche book", which is a book which appeals to a very small group of people. (It doesn't express this idea very well, as it's not clear what noun *niche* modifies here: it's not a "niche" suggestion, but a suggestion for a "niche" movie screening. So the grammar of the sentence is wrong, but the meaning of "niche" is standard.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Niche as an adjective means having [specialized appeal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/niche). In what seems an awkward use of the word, he is saying that his suggestion was a "bit niche" - it would have somewhat specialized appeal to a somewhat specialized market.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not wrong grammatically “niche” modifies “my suggestion” in that sentence. The verb “to be” does not take an object. The subject is followed by an adjective or an adverb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).